# Extend a line element using the two edges of line in SVG using Mouse in Javascript

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, line

I have a need to extend a line element using the two edges of line in SVG using Mouse

The line needs handle on two edges of line and be able extend

Is there any demo application for this kind of requirement, if so please share

Comment: <svg height="210" width="500">
  <line x1="0" y1="0" x2="200" y2="200" style="stroke:rgb(255,0,0);stroke-width:2" />
</svg>

Comment: Hi @Karthik and welcome to stackoverflow. You can edit your own post to include any addition details instead of adding them as comments. Please refer to [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more details to improve your chances of getting an answer.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.